# Rails 3 - Custom link_to helper (with default class and ability to add classes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper, link-to

I'm trying to hook up a custom helper that has a default class 'pjax' but also retains an ability to add classes where need be.

Example:

```
link_to_pjax('pagename', page_path, :class => 'current')
```

So the helper would add the 'pjax' by default, and also the class 'current', or whatever is passed in.

```
def link_to_pjax(name, path, options = {:class => 'pjax'})
    link_to(name, path, options)
end
```

The syntax is freaking me out. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: So in your example, are you looking to have it override the default class of 'pjax' or add the 'current' class to the 'pjax' class (eg: 'current pjax')?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def link_to_pjax(name, path, options)
  options[:class] += ' pjax'
  link_to(name, path, options)
end
```

**edit**

After test, it's much less elegant:

```
 def link_to_pjax(name, path, options = {})
   options[:class] ? options[:class] += ' pjax' : options[:class] = 'pjax'
   link_to(name, path, options)
 end
```

My first solution works but only if you have still specified a class.

The latest works in all cases:

- link_to_pjax 'click me', my_super_path, class: 'ahah', id: 'hello'
- link_to_pjax 'click me', my_super_path
- etc

My bad...

Comment: Thanks for that. How can I get it to work if no :class is specified on the original link_to?

Comment: I love it. Simple, and makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: The last link_to in the answer should use (name, path, options) instead of (text, url, options).

Answer (score 1):

```
def link_to_pjax(name, path, options={})
  default_options = { :class => "pjax" }
  link_to(name, path, options.merge(default_options))
end
```

Comment: I have that a whirl, and while it added the 'pjax' class, it seemed to strip my class on the initial link_to

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood the problem. @Delba's solution should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I improved Delba answer to handle block version of link_to:

```
def link_to_pjax(*args, &block)
  if block_given?
    options      = args.first || {}
    html_options = args.second
    link_to_pjax(capture(&block), options, html_options)
  else
    name         = args[0]
    options      = args[1] || {}
    html_options = args[2] || {}
    html_options[:class] ? html_options[:class] += ' pjax' : html_options[:class] = 'pjax'
    link_to(name, options, html_options)
  end
end
```